# How many lattice points are on the boundary or inside the region bounded by the $x$-axis, the line $x=4$ and the curve $y=2\sqrt{x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A lattice point is a point whose coordinates are both integers. How many lattice points are on the boundary or inside the region bounded by the $x$-axis, the line $x=4$ and the curve $y=2\sqrt{x}$?

I graphed this and I guess the x-axis is the bottom boundary for this figure. How can I determine the lattice points? I see that (4,4) is one of them (point of intersection.

Answer (score 1):

This region contains 5 lines x=0,1,2,3,4.

All the lattice points will lie on these lines.
So solving for each.

$$x=0, 0\le{y}\le2\sqrt{x}$$

i.e. integral values of y are 0.

Similarly for x=1, y=0,1,2.

x=2, y=0,1,2.

x=3, y=0,1,2,3.

x=4, y=0,1,2,3,4.

therefore, 16 points.

Answer (score 1):

It should be clear from your sketch that the lattice points that you need to count lie on the lines x=0, x=1, x=2, x=3 or x=4.

So we weant to count the number of integer values for y such that:

$0 \le y \le 2 \sqrt{x}$

for x = 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4. Each integer value for y for a given value of x gives a lattice point (x,y).

For x=0 there is one lattice point (0,0). For x=1 there are three lattice points (1,0), (1,1) and (1,2). I'll let you continue.